# Pivots with multiple value columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 5 columns.
Year, Month, A1, A2 & A3.

I need a summarized table based on year & month.

A1 should be a count with a criteria.
A2 should be a sum.
A3 should be a count.

I tried to do a pivot but it seems panda pivots pick only one column as value field.

I tried getting counts & sums for columns separately, but what I need is one summarized table

```
df1=df.loc[(df['A1'] == 'Y') | (df['A2'] == 'DY')].count()

df2=df['A2'].sum()

df3=df['A3'].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't provide a code I had to create my own DF so I hope I got it right, here is my solution:

1. Data:

```
np.random.seed(10)

data = {
    'Year': np.random.choice(["2015", "2016"], (10)),
    'Month': np.random.choice(["Jan", "September"], (10)),
    'A1': np.random.choice(["Y", "X"], (10)),
    'A2': np.random.choice(["DY", "DX"], (10)),
    'A3': np.random.choice(["A", "B"], (10)),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(["Year", "Month"])

   Year      Month A1  A2 A3
4  2015        Jan  X  DY  B
7  2015        Jan  Y  DY  A
2  2015  September  Y  DY  B
0  2016        Jan  Y  DY  B
3  2016        Jan  Y  DY  A
6  2016        Jan  Y  DX  A
8  2016        Jan  X  DX  A
9  2016        Jan  Y  DX  B
1  2016  September  X  DX  B
5  2016  September  X  DX  A
```

2. Groupby year and month:

```
groups = df.groupby(["Year", "Month"])
```

3. Get the aggregations required:

```
def specialSum(group):
    return ((group['A1'] == 'Y') | (group['A2'] == 'DY')).sum()

groups = df.groupby(["Year", "Month"])
pd.concat([groups.apply(lambda group: specialSum(group)).rename('A1'),
           groups.agg({'A2': 'sum', 'A3': 'count'})],
          axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                A1          A2  A3
Year Month                        
2015 Jan         2        DYDY   2
     September   1          DY   1
2016 Jan         4  DYDYDXDXDX   5
     September   0        DXDX   2
```

Hope it helps, if you have questions ask in comment, or if the data is not representative, update your question so that I can improve my answer, for example I don't think that the sum for A2 is what you want if A2 contains string, or my data don't look like yours.

> Documentation of the function used:
>
> [Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html): group rows based on values (can be series, mapped values, ...)
>
> [Groupby.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html): apply a function on the groups.
>
> [Groupby.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html): aggregate groups via specified agg function, can be done by a dict to specify different agg function for differents columns.
>
> [Concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html): concatenate DataFrame along the specified axis.